# How to scrape a webpage using Beautiful Soup as if using Chrome?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting certain elements in google chrome (Inspect) but not in internet explorer when I view the source of the same web page.

I assume Beautiful Soup uses internet explorer inside? Its results match IE more closely.

However when I use the Inspect feature of chrome, I see certain elements not listed in the source.

Is there a way I can emulate this in Python or using Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Did you try adding a user agent like ie or chrome?

Comment: no I will try this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your user agent's to one of the following:

https://webscraping.com/blog/User-agents/

> **A Snippet:** changing User-Agent forces the page to open different contets (mobile vs Chrome)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-G928X Build/LMY47X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get("http://derstandard.at", headers=headers)
c = result.content
print result.request.headers


print len(c)
```

**Note:** Some websites are protecting them selfes for `user-agent spoofing`. So not all websites might respond to these frequent jumps.

Comment: thx it seems like requests is another library i have to download? I get "ImportError: No module named requests"

Comment: Yes, basically it is a very convenient one. so it is highly suggested installing it if you want to do scraping. `pip install requests` if you are on a linux distro.

Comment: @JoanVenge It is no doubt that `requests` is the best http lib in python. Let's take it in use as soon as possible.

Comment: can this lib emulate Inspect feature of Chrome though?

Comment: for doing more elaborate things you should look into: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent